# What does $bean stand for and can I get SQL data in a field in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, sql, field, sugarcrm

What does `$bean` stand for in this code:

```
<?php
    // prevents directly accessing this file from a web browser
    if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry)
        die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class Process {

        function process(&$bean, $event) {
            // calculate item profit
            $bean->t_profit_c = ($bean->t_sale_price_c - $bean->t_item_cost_c);

            // calculate sale profit
            if (!empty($bean->t_qty_sold_c)) {
                $bean->t_sale_profit_c = ($bean->t_qty_sold_c * $bean->t_profit_c);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

[which I found here](http://ameronix.com/blog/2012/07/creating-custom-sugarcrm-module)

And can I use SQL queries in code like this to get other module's field's content to a field in an other?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Seems like you missed **in this code** bit.

Comment: `$bean` is an object being passed in by reference... can't tell you anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $bean is an object, or set of objects used by SugarCRM to allow the user to access database information quickly and easily. Working with them should be pretty easy:

[how to using the bean instead of sql all the time](http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2012/03/23/howto-using-the-bean-instead-of-sql-all-the-time/)

[Sugar_Developer](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/02_Application_Framework/Helper_Classes/BeanFactory)

In your instance, the `&$bean` is an object, passed by reference that holds all the attributes of the item you gave it in step 3 of your link.